# jQuery: window.opener makes a difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener

I'm working on localhost (so would expect to not have any domain-related probs as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813396/window-opener-is-not-right)).

On a page I'm using a bit of JS to modify the content of a span in the opening-window. It does not work. 
When checking my code to find the control, it works (using FF dev-tools calling my `Increment`-function or checking the `console.log`-output): `$('#uploads_Count')`returns an object of type HTMLSpanElement. However, trying to access the same control from an opened window's console with `window.opener.$('#uploads_Count')`, this returns an HTML-Document, seemingly the entire page. Why is this not working, what am I missing here?

Here is function that is supposed to increment the counter contained in the span whose id is given as argument:

```
function Increment(ctrl)
{
   var gef = $("#" + ctrl);
   if (!gef) // did not find control, maybe on opener?
   {
      gef = window.opener.$("#" + ctrl);
   }
   console.log(gef);

   cnt = parseInt(gef.text() , 10);
   cnt++;
   gef.text(cnt);
}
```

The HTML is trivial:

```
<span id="uploads_Count">0</span>
```

Comment: Can you actually show us the relevant parts of your HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Chrome dev tools have a built-in `$` selector which is *not* jQuery. It wouldn't surprise me if Firefox was the same. Are you *sure* that you have jQuery set up on the page?

Comment: @zzzzBov Firebug doesn't have its own `$` function, not sure about other developer tools plugins for Firefox.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Both [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Web_Console) have it.

Comment: @all: revided Q and edited code...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yeah, I was just being an idiot when checking whether they existed in Firebug. No `window.$` available from Firebug (unless jQuery is loaded on the page), though, so using that or `jQuery(...);` might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The way I checked if the control was found, was wrong. Instead of `if (!gef)`I should have used `if (!gef.length)`. Found the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877654/determining-whether-jquery-has-not-found-any-element).

Answer (score 0):

If `$(selector)` returns an element (such as `HTMLSpanElement`), rather than a collection of elements (would look like `[<span id="uploads_Count"></span>]` in most dev tools), then you're not calling `jQuery`.

Dev tools in A-grade browsers tend to introduce `$` as a selector function. It is available in the developer console only.

If `window.jQuery` exists, then it's likely that [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict) was called, in which case you should use `window.opener.jQuery`.

Comment: in jQuery the length of ID based elem $("#elem") is always 1 or 0. It doesn't gave any other result if more then one element with same div found on page.

Comment: As shown, I'm using $(selector) in my JS-code. However, I tried replacing `window.opener.$("#" + ctrl);`with `window.opener.jQuery('#' + ctrl) - but still the span is not being found.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta, the point I'm making is that `$` will return the actual `HTMLSpanElement` if it's the dev tools. If jQuery is set to `$`, then `$` will return a collection, which would be the elements selected wrapped by `[]`. If there's one element in the collection, it's still a collection.

Comment: @MBaas, how do you **know** that jQuery is on the page?

Comment: using this typeof jQuery == "function" will return true of jQuery is on the page.

Comment: @zzzzBov the expression (in ms .js-file) works when launching the function `Increment` while on the same page, and it does not work when launched from an opened page. It's from the same .JS-file and all the same .js files are loaded in both cases, so surely jQuery is there.

Comment: @MBaas, and did you check the debugger to look for any script errors, or network errors for loading?