# Being on a page, how to open a popup window containing a form that, when submitted, will update a select element from the 'caller' page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sorry but I don't know how to ask this better.

This is my main page:

[image: caller window image]

when I select the "New Element" option from the select element, a popup window (or whatever is named) should open:

[image: popup window image]

After the form is completed, the submit button should perfom a POST to the server in order to insert a new element
in the Data Base, the popup window should close automatically and the dropdown list must be selected in the newest inserted element

[image: caller window with the updated select element]

THE POPUP WINDOW **IS NOT PART OF THE DOM** of the main page.

How could I do this in jQuery? The popup window is a web page that will have to be loaded some how. I guess that I should 
do a jQuery.post() to send the data from the popup window to the server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for this, and use `querystrings` to populate your popUp window.

So your select box would look something like this:

```
 <select onChange="popUp(this.value);">
   <option value="0">New Element</option>
   <option value="1">Element 1</option>
   <option value="2">Element 2</option>
   <option value="3">Element 3</option>
 </select>
```

Then your `popUp()` function would look like this:

```
 function popUp(val) {
   window.open('mypopupwindow.php?element=' + val,'_target','width=400,height=400');
 }
```

I would use some sort of server side language on `mypopupwindow.php` , otherwise you would need to use javascript to read the querystrings in the url to populate your text box.

Comment: thanks Zee, I understand that this code is for opening the popup window but the real important thing is to update the dropdown list of the caller page with the element inserted from the popup window.

Comment: As I said, you would populate the url with Querystrings `url?querystring=value` and then would read that querystring in your popup window either using a server-side language, or javascript as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Zee, I'm testing your suggestion but I don't need to populate the popup windows. What I need is to 're populate' the select element in the page that calls the popup, with the new element inserted in the popup window..

Comment: Actually, view this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034903/jquery-write-to-opener-window

Comment: Thanks Zee, it was what I needed.I wish I could set your comment as the accepted answer =)